# Sorting by using the value of array (VB.NET)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

The input :

```
i = 768
arrayInt(i) = 258
arrayIntCombine(i) = 256
arrayByte(i) = 32

i = 1632
arrayInt(i) = 256
arrayIntCombine(i) = 112
arrayByte(i) = 97

i = 1824
arrayInt(i) = 259
arrayIntCombine(i) = 32
arrayByte(i) = 112

i = 1889
arrayInt(i) = 257
arrayIntCombine(i) = 97
arrayByte(i) = 112

i = 2016
arrayInt(i) = 260
arrayIntCombine(i) = 256
arrayByte(i) = 110

..... (more input)
```

I would like an output like this (text or messagebox):

```
No. 256 : 112 and 97
No. 257 : 97 and 112
No. 258 : 256 and 32
No. 259 : 32 and 112
No. 260 : 256 and 110
...... (more output)
```

I've tried array.sort from [Sorting an array numerically (VB.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092248/sorting-an-array-numerically-vb-net) but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Tuples:

```
    Dim DictionaryOfTuples As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer))
    DictionaryOfTuples(768) =
        New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)(258, 256, 32)
    DictionaryOfTuples(1632) =
        New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)(256, 112, 97)
    DictionaryOfTuples(1824) =
        New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)(259, 32, 112)
    DictionaryOfTuples(1889) =
        New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)(257, 97, 112)
    DictionaryOfTuples(2016) =
        New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)(260, 256, 110)

    Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each sortedTuple In DictionaryOfTuples.Values.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Item1)
        output.AppendLine(
            String.Format(
                "No. {0} : {1} and {2}",
                sortedTuple.Item1,
                sortedTuple.Item2,
                sortedTuple.Item3))
    Next

    MsgBox(output.ToString)
```