# How to sort list numerically

Tags: vb.net

If I enter in, for example, 1, 30, 200, 68, and 49 I'll end up with this.

1
200
30
49
68

How do I end up with this.

1
30
49
68
200

```
    Dim nombres As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    nombres.Add(n1)
    nombres.Add(n2)
    nombres.Add(n3)
    nombres.Add(n4)
    nombres.Add(n5)
    Listbox1.sorted = True


    For Each item In nombres
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next`
```

Comment: `array.sort(nombres)` Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092248/sorting-an-array-numerically-vb-net

Comment: Setting ListBox.Sorted will result in the same problem regardless of ordering the source array as that will sort based on the string representation of the integer values

Comment: Sort the source data, not the control. The `List(Of T)` class has its own `Sort` method, or you could use the LINQ `OrderBy` method.

Comment: OT, don't add items to a `ListBox` in a loop. Either call `AddRange` once or, preferably, use data-binding by setting the `DataSource`.

Comment: @nowendwell, the principle is right but there's no array here.

Comment: `Dim nombres As New List(Of Integer)({1, 30, 200, 68, 49}) nombres.Sort() ListBox1.DataSource = nombres`